# PHP fileupload: keep both files if same name

Tags: php, file-upload, file-rename

is there any pretty solution in PHP which allows me to expand filename with an auto-increment number if the filename already exists? I dont want to rename the uploaded files in some unreadable stuff. So i thought it would be nice like this: (all image files are allowed.)

```
Cover.png
Cover (1).png
Cover (2).png
…
```

Comment: using file_exists() function you can achieve this very simply

Comment: But file_exists delivers me only true or false…

Comment: ya,you need to take care of further stuff,write simple algorithm first then implement it in coding,it makes easier to you

Comment: "simple algorithm" ? ja, basically i know what do you mean but ive no idea how to resolve that. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let's separate extension and filename:

```
$file=pathinfo(<your file>);
```

For easier file check and appending, save filename into new variable:

```
$filename=$file['filename'];
```

Then, let's check if file already exists and save new filename until it doesn't:

```
$i=1;
while(file_exists($filename.".".$file['extension'])){
 $filename=$file['filename']." ($i)";
 $i++;
}
```

Here you go, you have a original file with your `<append something>` that doesn't exist yet.

**EDIT:**
Added auto increment number.

Comment: pretty easy!!! :) but the auto increment solution is better i think. But thanks!!!

Comment: @Salman A: In what way? I double checked and I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: I mean what does `$filename." ($i)";` do? I don't see any assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Got it:

```
if (preg_match('/(^.*?)+(?:\((\d+)\))?(\.(?:\w){0,3}$)/si', $FILE_NAME, $regs)) {
        $filename = $regs[1];
        $copies = (int)$regs[2];
        $fileext = $regs[3];

        $fullfile = $FILE_DIRECTORY.$FILE_NAME;
        while(file_exists($fullfile) && !is_dir($fullfile))
        {
                $copies = $copies+1;
                $FILE_NAME = $filename."(".$copies.")".$fileext;
                $fullfile = $FILE_DIRECTORY.$FILE_NAME;
        }
}
return $FILE_NAME;
```

Comment: You could use [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) instead of regex; much simpler this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function below to get unique name for uploading

```
function get_unique_file_name($path, $filename) {
    $file_parts = explode(".", $filename);
    $ext = array_pop($file_parts);
    $name = implode(".", $file_parts);

    $i = 1;
    while (file_exists($path . $filename)) {
        $filename = $name . '-' . ($i++) . '.' . $ext;
    }
    return $filename;
}
```

Use that function as

```
$path = __DIR__ . '/tmp/';
$fileInput = 'userfile';

$filename = $path . 
    get_unique_file_name($path, basename($_FILES[$fileInput]['name']));

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fileInput]['tmp_name'], $filename)) {
    return $filename;
}
```

You can get working script [here at github page](https://github.com/tofeeq/utils-php/blob/master/upload.php)

Answer (score -2):

Use `file_exists()` function and `rename()` function to achieve what you're trying to do!

Comment: Do i need any regex for that? Sure i can check if the original filename already exist but what if i am trying to upload another Cover.png. How can i recognize how many are there already?